# spotify app navigation

Tags: spotify

In the people app that comes with spotify when you click on a users photo it loads new content from the list of people by taking you to a differnt uri, as such the navigation works correctly using the navigation buttons.

I have working navigation tabs A B C [as described in the spotify UI Guidelines](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/guidelines/03_ui-guidelines.html#topnavigation) that have an event listener

```
sp.core.addEventListener("argumentsChanged", tabUpdate);
```

If I click A then B then C I can navigate back through the tabs using the spotify back and forward buttons.

When I click A it gives me a list of results D, when I click on a result in D it loads new content E without changing the tab. **My question is how should i go about navigating back to the list of results D**?

I cant click on A again as it is already selected.

Is there another event I can listen for? Do I need to load E into a new page or is there a more elegant way of doing the navigation that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [guidelines](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/guidelines/):

`You can also push new states programmatically, by setting window.location to spotify:app:$APPNAME:arguments".`

You can also see a working example of an app using tabs here https://github.com/ptrwtts/kitchensink

Comment: cheers i had just got it working from looking at your code, this snippet // args[0] = page,  args[1] = command, args[2] = value // e.g. spotify:app:kitchensink:search:play:the+cure+close+to+me was exactly what i was after