# possible spotify programmatic navigation bug? 

Tags: spotify

#### Possible bug description

[following on from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713228/spotify-app-navigation/) I think there is a bug in the [Integrating with the Spotify Application’s History](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/guidelines/#functionalityguidelines) if I create tabs A, B, C where A contains a list D.
If I click

```
A --> B --> C --> A
```

this could be done programmatically as

```
spotify:app:appname:A
spotify:app:appname:B
spotify:app:appname:C
spotify:app:appname:A
```

which works fine. However if I click

```
A --> A:D --> C --> A --> B
```

this could be done programmatically as

```
spotify:app:appname:A
spotify:app:appname:A:D
spotify:app:appname:C
spotify:app:appname:A
spotify:app:appname:B
```

Which allows me to click back on A if I am viewing A:D (solving the problem of my original post)

However when I click through the second sequence and view the state of

```
sp.core.getArguments();
```

the second sequence shows up as

```
spotify:app:appname:A
spotify:app:appname:A:D
spotify:app:appname:C
spotify:app:appname:A:D
spotify:app:appname:B
```

#### Implication 1

If I use the state and creating the display with something like

```
  sp.core.addEventListener("argumentsChanged", tabUpdate);

function tabUpdate(po) {
    var args = sp.core.getArguments();     
    switch(args[0])
    {
      case "A":
        showA(args);
        break;
      case "B":
        showB();
        break;
      case "C":
        showC();
        break;
    }
```

it would display incorrectly as the :D is attached to the tab A when I just click on tab A.

#### Implication 2

If I just use the state so that the browse sees A and A:D as different (aka I can get back to A from A:D by clicking on the tab)

Fixing the display changes with an onclick element for the list D that would mean that it works clicking forward. However using the navigation buttons to go backwards will show up incorrectly. Ie if I click through then use the back button it will display

```
B --> A --> C --> A --> A
```

instead of

```
B --> A --> C --> A:D --> A
```

#### Alternative 2

with the same setup described above but using the reference to D on its own.

```
spotify:app:appname:A
spotify:app:appname:D
spotify:app:appname:C
spotify:app:appname:A
```

shows up as

```
spotify:app:appname:A
spotify:app:appname:D:A
spotify:app:appname:C
spotify:app:appname:D:A
```

Which means that when I click back to A from C it doesnt display A.

#### Question

Is there a way to get around this?

I can put together an app to replicate this if required.

Answer (score 2):

I know what you're talking about and I can confirm that this problem exists.

Put simply, if you're on tab A, and you navigate inside that tab pushing to window.location, when you go to tab B and you click back on tab A, you get the same arguments which you got the last time you looked at tab A.

I think this actually makes sense because it maintains state history on each tab, BUT there are cases where you don't want this to happen, depending on your app's workflow.

One could use the argumentsChanged event handler to check for this but there is a problem: you can't tell whether argumentsChanged has been fired by clicking on a tab or by pushing the back/forward buttons.

If the event object passed to the argumentsChanged event handler could inform whether the user has clicked a tab or is navigating using back/forward buttons, then a developer could very easily solve these workflows.